# Why does 1,2-dimethylcyclohexane only possess three stereoisomers?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, cyclohexane

> Why does 1,2-dimethylcyclohexane in chair form have only three stereoisomers?

I understand that the *trans* isomer doesn't possess plane of symmetry and thus it has two stereoisomers. But my book says that the *cis* isomer has does not have two  stereoisomers. Why is this so?

[image: cis-1,2-dimethylcyclohexane]

The structure of *cis*-1,2-dimethylcyclohexane is shown above. Its mirror image is non-superimposable and cannot be obtained by rotation about single single bonds or by a ring flip. Can anyone explain?Thanks

Comment: Related: [Enantiomers of 1,2-dichlorocyclohexane](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/83877/7951)

Comment: Draw the other conformation...

Comment: Related, bordering on duplicate? [Is cis-1,2-dimethylcyclohexane a meso compound?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/61107/16683)

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/87847/why-is-trans-1-2-dimethylcyclohexane-an-enantiomer

Answer (score 1):

Quoting , ORGANIC CHEMISTRY second edition by JOSEPH M. HORNBACK, UNIVERSITY OF DENVER

1,2-dimethylcyclohexane has two chirality centers.
[image]

The cis-diastereomer has a plane of symmetry bisecting the ring bond between
the two methyl groups  and therefore a meso compound.It is not chiral and does not rotate plane-polarized light.The trans-diastereomer exists as a pair of enantiomers.

The chair conformation of cis-1,2-dimethylcyclohexane  shows that it is chiral.
But due to  ring-flip , another  conformation ,its  enantiomer of the original conformation is also formed.These conformers interconvert rapidly at room temperature, therefore cis-1,2-dimethylcyclohexane is not chiral.

Further I quote

"stereochemical analyses such as the preceding one can be done with drawings using planar rings" pg.235.

A molecule cannot be optically active if its chiral conformations are in
equilibrium with their mirror images. We consider such a molecule to
be achiral. PG- 193 - ORGANIC CHEMISTRY  .EIGHTH EDITION
L.G. WADE , JR . WHITMAN COLLEGE